# Course suggestion for BDD Framework using POM and Python (Selenium Automation)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, bdd, pom

I tried to find an automation course that includes bdd framework with pom and Pyhton but I am not able to find any course regarding can you help me to find a link of such course

Comment: Voting for closing, because this StackExchange is focused on testing. For software development (Behavior-Driven Development), StackOverflow would be a more fit community.